# Landscaping in Rave Reports using Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, rave-reports

I have an application that uses Rave Reports on Delphi 7. I want the reports to have its default display in landscape. How am I going to do it?

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just drop TRvSystem component and set SystemPrinter.Orientation to poLandScape. exemple:

```
RvSystem1.SystemPrinter.Orientation := poLandScape;
```